# Quicksort Algorithm,Incorrect answer and segmentation fault with some specific input sequences

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am learning c++ and I am relatively new to programming. I wrote a C++ program that implements the quick sort algorithm using the last element as the pivot. Whenever I try to execute it, the answer is always wrong and for some specific input sequences I get a segmentation fault error.

I have tried playing around with the while loop and changing it to "if" statements to see if anything happens. The results change but they are incorrect.

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int partition(int a[],int l,int r)
{
//int l=0,r=p-1;
    int p=r+1;
    while(r>l)
    {
        while (a[l]<a[p])
        {
            l=l+1;
        }

        while(a[r]>a[p])
        {
            r=r-1;
        }
        //if(a[l]>a[r]){
        int f=a[r];
        a[r]=a[l];
        a[l]=f;
        //}
    }
    int k=a[l];
    a[l]=a[p];
    a[p]=a[l];
    p=l;

    return p;
}

void quicksort(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    int p;
    if (l<r){
        p=partition(a,l,r);
        quicksort(a,0,p-2);
        quicksort(a,p+1,r);
    }
}

int main(){
    int k;
    cout<<"enter the number of elements in array";
    cin>>k;
    int a[k];
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    //int p=k-1;
    int l=0;
    int r=k-2;
    quicksort(a,l,r);
    for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

actual results:
enter the number of elements in array
4

3
0
1
2

sorted result
1322

expected results:
0123

Comment: Now is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). But first try to format your code a little better. Indentation and blank lines might not matter for the compiler, but it does matter a *lot* for people (including yourself) reading the code.

Comment: You're using the wrong bounds in the recursions.

Comment: There are some mysterious "adjustments" (`-2` almost never occurs in an algorithm) that makes it look like you're spending too much time guessing when you could be thinking and reading.

Comment: I am sorry. I saw a lot of implementations of the program when i was reading about it but i chose not to look at someone else's code because i wanted to do it by myself without any assistance as I thought it would help me learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the posted code is [compiled](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gb3F6meXqxLZ3biz) with warnings enabled, the following diagnostic is produced:

```
 prog.cc:25:9: warning: unused variable 'k' [-Wunused-variable]
    int k=a[l];
        ^
prog.cc:47:10: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
    int a[k];
         ^
```

The first one is generated by what seems to be a typo in function `partition`:

```
int k=a[l];
a[l]=a[p];
a[p]=a[l];  // <-- That should be 'a[p] = k;' to swap the values
```

Of course, the proper way of swapping those two values should be

```
std::swap(a[l], a[p]);
```

The second warning is easily fixed by using the proper data structure, which in C++ is a `std::vector` and passing a reference to it to the other functions, instead of a `int *`.

Those aren't the only issues in OP's code, which seems to implement a variant of the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm using the Lomuto partition scheme.

In OP's code the first call is something like

```
quicksort(a, 0, k - 2); // k beeing the size of the VLA, it skips the last element
```

While, using a `vector` and following the convention of denoting a range by its first element and the one past the end, we could write the entry point as

```
// Note that std::vector::size() returns an unsigned type
quicksort(a, 0, a.size());
```

So that the `quicksort` function could be implemented as

```
void quicksort(std::vector<int> &a, size_t low, size_t high)
{
    if ( low < high) {
        size_t p = partition(a, low, high);
        quicksort(a, low, p);           // <- Note that OP's code uses '0' instead of 'low'
        quicksort(a, p + 1, high);
    }
}
```

If I correctly guessed the variant which the OP is trying to implement, the partition function could be simplified (and fixed) to

```
size_t partition(std::vector<int> &a, size_t low, size_t high)
{
    size_t p = high - 1; // <- Assumes high > 0
    size_t i = low;
    for( size_t j = low; j < p; ++j )
    {
        if(a[j] < a[p]) {
            std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    std::swap(a[i], a[p]);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I made a lot of silly mistakes. Thank you very much for your assistance. I skipped the last element since the last element in the array was supposed to be the pivot. I mentioned it in the function when i declared p= r+1 . I will try to fix the mistakes and see what happens. Once again, thank you very much.